# How to view a React native debugger menu in React Native module integrated in existing Android App?

Tags: react-native

I have an existing Android App.

I have designed one of the screens of the App with React Native. So, now it becomes an Hybrid App (Android + React Native).

While designing the React Native screen I wanted to quickly debug it or refresh it to see any design change quickly.

Hence wanted to open the Debug menu, as it happens in a non-integrated React native App.

When I press r+r the screen doesn't refresh as it does in a non-integrated React native App run on Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> command + m

Or

> ctrl + m

to see your developer menu in android emulators. If it still not shows up, then you may have to move on to the activity/the screen in which you access the react-native module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ansal. For me even cmd + m was also not working in Integrated app. Just answered the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the React Native debugging in Android React Native Integrated App,
please enable the debug flag during configuration - setUseDeveloperSupport("true")

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()

            .setApplication(getApplication())

            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")

            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")

            .setUseDeveloperSupport("true")

            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)

            .build();

     mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager,    
    "YourApp", appProps);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

Then if you are using real mobile device, then shake it, which will open up the Debugging overlay.
You might also face an issue with permission. Please refer the below to resolve it:

https://medium.com/react-native-development/fixing-problems-in-react-native-caused-by-new-permission-model-on-android-1e547f754b8